# object string will not show in razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a form in a view with various inputs, although one of these inputs must not be `null` `(TeacherName)`. If a user leaves this field blank, the model state will not be valid so they will be passed back to the `HttpGet BookingForm` action (some object information is passed back with the user; `RollNumber`, `Date` and a `Validation Message`).

When the user is passed back to the Form I need to show the `ValidationMsg` in the view at the top of the form. Although I can not get the message to show up in the view. However, the `ValidationMsg` is being passed in the URL as I can see this in the URL: `0&ValidationMsg=Please%20complete%20all%20fields`

Can anyone tell me why the `ValidationMsg` is not showing up in the View when the user gets returned `RedirectToAction` to `BookingForm`?

**My controllers:**

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult BookingForm(School model)
    {
        School school = db.Schools.First(m => m.RollNumber == 
model.RollNumber);
        return View(school);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("BookingForm")]
    public ActionResult BookingFormPost(Booking model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Bookings.Add(model);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
        }

        var newModel = new School();
        newModel.RollNumber = model.RollNumber;
        newModel.Date = model.Date;
        string ValidateMsg = "Please complete all fields";
        newModel.ValidationMsg = ValidateMsg;
        return RedirectToAction("BookingForm", newModel);
    }
```

**My model:**

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RollNumber { get; set; }
    public string OfficialSchoolName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A teacher name is required")]
    public string TeacherName { get; set; }

    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
```

**View:**

```
@model CampBookingSys.Models.School

@{
ViewBag.Title = "School Booking Form";
}

<h2>School Booking Form</h2>


<form asp-controller="School" asp-action="BookingForm" method="post">
<p>@Model.ValidationMsg</p>

<br />

<p>Please complete the following information</p>

<div>
    <label for="RollNumber">School Roll Number:</label>
    <br />
    <input asp-for="Booking.Rollnumber" id="txtRoll" name="RollNumber" 
value="@Model.RollNumber" />
</div>
<br />
<div>
    <label for="Date">Choose Camp Date:</label>
    <br />
    <input asp-for="Booking.Date" id="txtDate" name="Date" 
value="@Model.Date.Value.ToShortDateString()" />
</div>
<br />
<div>
    <label for="OfficialSchoolName">School Name:</label>
    <br />
    <input asp-for="Booking.OfficialSchoolName" id="txtOfficialSchoolName" 
name="OfficialSchoolName" value="@Model.OfficialSchoolName" />
</div>
<br />
<div>
    <label for="TeacherName">Teacher Name:</label>
    <br />
    <input asp-for="Booking.TeacherName" id="txtTeacherName" 
name="TeacherName" />
</div>
<br />
<div>
    <label for="Email">Teacher Email:</label>
    <br />
    <input asp-for="Booking.Email" id="txtEmail" name="Email" />
</div>
<br />
<div>
    <label for="PhoneNumber">Teacher Contact Number:</label>
    <br />
    <input asp-for="Booking.PhoneNumber" id="txtPhoneNumber" 
name="PhoneNumber" value="@Model.PhoneNumber" />
</div>
<br />
<div>
    <label for="Surveys">Would you like to take part in research surveys? 
</label>
    <br />
    <input asp-for="Booking.Surveys" id="Surveys" name="Surveys" 
type="checkbox" onclick="$(this).val(this.checked ? true : false)" />
</div>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />
</form>
```

Cheers

Comment: Why you are not checking this while submitting your form?

Comment: I am not quite sure how to do it correctly. I tried to add '@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TeacherName).ToHtmlString()))' under the TeacherName label and could not make it work, if you could post a quick answer on how to do this correctly for my situation I would be grateful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are populating the school model in the `Post` action. You don't have to use `RedirectToAction` instead use `return View` itself. It should work.

In your `HttpGet` action you are repopulating your school model, that is why `RedirectToAction` not working.

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("BookingForm")]
public ActionResult BookingFormPost(Booking model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Bookings.Add(model);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
    }

    var newModel = new School();        
    newModel = db.Schools.First(m => m.RollNumber == model.RollNumber);
    newModel.Date = model.Date;
    string ValidateMsg = "Please complete all fields";
    newModel.ValidationMsg = ValidateMsg;
    return View("BookingForm", newModel);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need to pass a School model into the HttpGet action, while the HttpPost action takes a Booking model. If I was to use return View(model) then it would return the incorrect model (Booking instead of School)

Comment: School school = db.Schools.First(m => m.RollNumber == 
model.RollNumber); school.ValidationMsg = ValidateMsg;
        return View(school); why couldn't you use this in the HttpPost itself?

Comment: check my updated answer, also I would recommend making using Html helpers for validations https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.validationextensions.validationmessagefor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

Comment: Quite new to c# and asp.net. You're solution works thanks a lot for your time and help

Comment: cheers :) out of curiosity, is this situation would it be possible to use   Html.EditorFor and Html.LabelFor even though I am passing a School object into the view but adding Booking object data?

Comment: so you use school model in view, but while posting you are using booking object. If the properties in the booking model and school model are same, asp.net will map the data correctly even if you use html helpers itself. If the properties are different I would use school model as parameter in the HTTP Post and then map the data to booking model from school model before calling the save method